# CSS Issue on a specific web page

Tags: css, html, templates

We are instituting a new responsive web template design on our website, this design has worked perfectly in all but one place (We are on the Convio CMS if that helps). Here is what it is supposed to look like (menu and contact info in right column):

http://www.ucc.org/feed-your-spirit/practices/prayer-flags.html

On this page however:

http://www.ucc.org/find/find-a-ucc-church.html

that info appears below here. However after you use the find feature, the information then DOES appear on the right side as it should. This really has me stumped.

The find a church service is a component that can be placed on any page.

Secondary issue - the map is not visible on the results page in Firefox, though on the current page - www.ucc.org/find - it is visible.

Any solutions, ideas, etc. are welcome!

Comment: Try and keep questions to just one at a time please. You should ask your map question in a separate SO question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one! But I'm thinking this might not be CSS.

My first reaction was that maybe a DIV isn't properly closed somewhere.

Based on the Find function fixing it, maybe you have a `</div>` that's set to display with the Find results, so it's not showing up before the Find function brings it up?

Hope that makes sense! If possible, try searching for any closing tags that are inside any kind of if/else statement.

EDIT - just noticed - A lot of the content in your Find a Church page seems to be after the 'three fourth' DIV, and after a 'clear' DIV. If you can edit the source, try placing all of that back inside the 'three fourth' DIV and see what happens.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here, I think there is a unclosed div in the "Find a Church" component - which is created elsewhere in the system...

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, both CSS. The left div, `ef-inner3` does not have `float:left` nor `width` specified. This causes it to be too wide, pushing the topics area down.

You need to add those CSS values in. How you do that with your particular CMS system I am not sure.

The reason behind it moving down is thus: When you float two elements, their combined widths cannot be greater than the width of their parent. If they are greater then there is not enough room and the second floated item moves below the first.

Comment: ef-inner3 covers the entire page width, the left and right sides are divided into three_fourth and one_fourth div. It seems as though the one_fourth div is somehow being set outside the ef-inner3? But once you do the search it is back in the correct place: http://www.ucc.org/find/find-a-ucc-church.html?radius=10&zip=43438. This has to be happening by the inclusion of the "Find a church" component...

Comment: Sounds like Ally was on the right track then. She edited her answer, see if you can do what she suggested.